# Qt vs Swing : Similarities and Disimilarities?

Tags: swing, qt

Do they have any common concepts like C++ and Java do? So that, anyone who learn either gets the basics of other? Like C++ and Java share some common concepts of OOP. You learn them in Java, you can apply them in C++ too and vice versa. Do, Qt and Swing has such property?

Comment: Well, that doesn't answer. I wanted to know whether knowing Qt teaches me some aspects of Swing and Vice Versa.

Comment: No, I don't think they have anything in common other than being widget-based GUI libraries.

Comment: Could you please write it as an answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

Since I have used both Swing and QT, I think that they do have some commons and being familiar with one can help you to learn the other faster. A good example is layouts. For example a grid layout is a grid layout no matter whether QT or Swing (or any other GUI library I guess) is used. The fundamental difference between the two frameworks is the event based nature of Swing (basically implementing listeners for everything and catching the generated events that interest you) vs. the slots and signals mechanism of QT.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I think I've wasted a great amount of time studying Swing. I don't know about Qt. But, at first I was excited to know its cross platform. Now I know ... everyone out there share this common slogan. In fact there is nothing like 'standard' or 'cross-platform' in this fragile earth.

Comment: You are welcome. I believe that QT is definitely faster and I find the signals and slots mechanism more flexible than the event-based mechanism.

Comment: As a long-time Swing developer learning Qt, this is very useful to know. I do hope Qt is as close to being cross-platform as Swing, though; although some problems do exist, Swing has always felt luxuriously cross-platform... then again, I also did web development for a living in the 1990s and 2000s. :-P